# YouTube Plugin in CKEditor Django returns 404

Tags: python, django, youtube, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I've been trying to install the YouTube plugin in CKEditor for a project, but I have failed and I couldn't figure out why.

I have configured my settings.py in the following manner (stripping it of irrelevant-to-this-issue code:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar_Collective':[
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic'],

            # ...

            {
                'name': 'links',
                'items': ['Link', 'Unlink']
            },
            {
                'name': 'media',
                'items': ['ImageButton', 'Youtube']
            },

            # ...

            {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize']},
            ],
        'toolbar':'Collective',
        'width': '100%',
        'height': 400,
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
        ]),
    }
}
```

Currently I have left the 'extraPlugins' configurations empty, because as soons as I write 'youtube' in there:

```
'extraPlugins': ','.join([
  'youtube',
 ]),
```

CKEditor fails, and the following is shown on my terminal:

```
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /post/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7239
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[16/Jan/2018 18:31:16] "GET /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js?t=H4PG HTTP/1.1" 404 1749
Performing system checks...
```

You can see there are other error codes, even regarding the page css. I don't know why they are there, but they are there regardless of any editing, and the editor functions regardless of them. The real issue is with the YouTube plugin (which is the only plugin I currently plan on having installed).

I have also tried configuring my `models.py` file with the RichTextUploadingField that is mentioned in the docs, and I've done the following:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # ...
    text = RichTextField(
        config_name='default',
        extra_plugins=['youtube'],
        external_plugin_resources=[(
            'Youtube',
            '/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/',
            'plugin.js',
        )],
    )
    #...
```

Which has also been fruitless. I have done the same in forms.py as well, and as both of these editings out of settings.py had no result whatsoever, I am back to my previous configuration, with only settings.py being edited.

I have searched extensively, and I have found mostly contradictory or incomplete information. That, or I didn't know how to process that information and did everything wrong.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your error just says that could not find /static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/youtube/plugin.js. so question if it really there ?
It's may be not in scope of question, but CKEditor is not required to be implemented with Django Backend, you can just add it in your template with html / js.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the plugin folder in your static directory?
If not then first download the "youtube" plugin folder from this link:

[https://download.ckeditor.com/youtube/releases/youtube_2.1.14.zip](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/youtube)

After unzipping it paste in the following directory of your django project

/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins

Now try to run this as ckeditor is looking for the file "plugin.js" in order to run some GET request which is not available in your situation that's why it is showing 404

Answer (score 0):

In the development environment static_root is not used to serve static files. So, if you want youtube plugin in development then inside of staticfiles_dir folder you have to create "ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins" folder structure and paste youtube plugin's extracted folder inside of plugins folder.

In production static_root folder will be used.